# Adding an Authorization header to a Service Reference SOAP request

Tags: c#, web-services

I've consumed a WSDL as and have succesfully called web-service methods.The request has an Authorization header that can only be added at the point the request is made:

```
    public static NumberCaptureClient Connect()
    {
        var remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://website.com:8443/webservice/WebServiceNumberCapture");

        using (var NumberCaptureClient = new NumberCaptureClient(new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport), remoteAddress))
        {
            NumberCapture.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
            NumberCapture.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test";

            try
            {
                using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(NumberCaptureClient.InnerChannel))
                {
                    var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();

                    httpRequestProperty.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " +
                    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(NumberCaptureClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + NumberCaptureClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));

                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
                return null;
            }

            return NumberCaptureClient;
        }    
    }
```

As you can see I'm in need of returning an instance of the proxy client (the client has hundereds of methods that all need the header) but need it so the headers are always sent, with the 'using' clause this isn't possible as the scope is lost outside of it.

Is there a way to permanantly add the headers so they are sent with every request to the webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a WCF proxy, right? Generally speaking, you should remove the `using` from your `Connect` method. If the method is used to get a prepared service proxy, then it makes no sense to dispose it as part of the method that creates it.

Instead, the method/code that uses the `Connect` method should be responsible of `using` it:

```
using(var proxy = theClass.Connect()) 
{
    // call service using proxy here

    // process response here, if you may need to call the service again
    // as part of processing
}
// process response here if you don't need to call the service again
```

There is a catch however, since for `WCF` proxies, the `Dispose` method internally calls the `Close` method, which in turn can throw exceptions. For this reason, Microsoft has a recommendation for how to handle cleaning up of WCF proxies. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, got a little tunnel vision there. working perfectly now.